# jquery .hover loads in reverse when mouseover

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I'm working with a simple jQuery function

```
$( 'foo' ).hover( function () {
     $( this ).children( 'bar' ).delay( 250 ).stop( true, true ).slideToggle( 200 );
})
```

I noticed that if I load the page with the mouse over the 'foo' element then the hover fires in reverse. I shows on mouseleave and hides on mouseover.

Any good solutions for this?

Comment: The code you have is for hiding element on hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `.hover` is in fact two events grouped in one: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. You have two ways to use it, either specify a function for each event or define one function that will be triggered on both event. That's what you're doing there, so your function will be triggered both on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

See https://api.jquery.com/hover/

If you want it to be trigerred only on `mouseenter`, you need to set it following this structure: `.hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )`. Like this:

```
    $( 'foo' ).hover( function () {
         function(){
          //this will be triggered only on mouseenter
           $( this ).children( 'bar' ).delay( 250 ).stop( true, true ).slideToggle( 200 );
         },
         function(){
         //insert here the behavior you want on mouseleave, if any
         }
    })
```

If you don't need any behavior on `mouseleave`, you can simply change `.hover` for `.mouseenter`. Like this:

```
$( 'foo' ).mouseenter( function () {
     $( this ).children( 'bar' ).delay( 250 ).stop( true, true ).slideToggle( 200 );
})
```

Comment: Ah that fixes it.  Also explains something else that was happening.  I'm surprised it worked as well as it did considering.  Thanks.